# Is "banco de trabajo" appropriate for a virtual workbench?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, español-neutral, informática

I have an application which we are translating into Spanish.  In it we have a page where the user can see the current week and all of their upcoming orders that they need to work with.  We call that page "Workbench" in the menu in English.  It is currently translated as "Banco de Trabajo" in Spanish.  I just want to confirm that the metaphor aspect translates well.  Also confirmation that this is neutral/Latin America Spanish.

Comment: Note that it should be "Banco de trabajo". Capitalizing every word in a title is considered [a mistake](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=may%C3%BAsculas) by the RAE (unless the word is a proper name, of course).

Comment: Also, [mesón de trabajo](https://www.google.com/search?q=mes%C3%B3n&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM-eq0mP7SAhXDHZAKHX_VDHoQ_AUICSgC&biw=1920&bih=957#safe=active&tbm=isch&q=mes%C3%B3n+de+trabajo&*). But a composite name may not sound as good as _workbench_, IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's OK. "Banco de trabajo" is the table (not the bench) that a carpenter or a fitter and turner use, where they normally have the vise and so many other tools. So it is just as wrong and just as correct as "workbench" (which has the same meaning and is also a table) :-)

At least in Buenos Aires "Banco de trabajo" is more common than "mesa de trabajo" which also exists, but is rare.

Comment: I agree however notice that "banco" = "bench" also in Spanish. Check RAE http://dle.rae.es/?id=4wkKYpU **Banco=1. m. Asiento, con respaldo o sin él, en que pueden sentarse dos o más personas.** however the second definition of _banco_ is what you described as the carpenters table (2. m. Madero grueso escuadrado que se coloca horizontalmente sobre cuatro pies y sirve de mesa para labores de carpinteros y otros artesanos.) +1